# Easier way to add lots of images to an array

Tags: iphone, arrays

In an effort to 'clean up' my code - I was wondering if this could be made simpler.
I have 32 images and I was adding them like this

```
 [theCarPics addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];
 [theCarPics addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"]];
 //...
 [theCarPics addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"32.jpg"]];
```

is there a simpler way? loop perhaps?

Any ideas would be appreciated guys

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Problems like this make you miss globing in scripting languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int c=1; c<=kNumberOfCars; c++)
{
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg", c];
    [theCarPics addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
}
```

*Update:* The `kNumberOfCars` is just a constant, of course. You can replace it by an actual value or (better) declare it somewhere at the top of your file:

```
static const int kNumberOfCars = 32;
```

Comment: thats just not working for some reason... ive changed it to this.

 
        for (int c = 1; c < 32; c++){
   NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg", c];
   [theCarPics addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
  }

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot we are counting from one. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: ah... i figured it out - i hadn't init'd the array *d'uh*